# What is the most convenient possibility to rent a kayak for the Allier?

Tags: france, rental, water-sports, sport-equipment, canoeing-and-kayaking

A friend and I are members in a kayaking club in Germany, and want to go to our club's tour on the Allier. We have a common friend who is interested in coming along, but she is not officially a club member, and it is possible that the club leaders cannot allow that.

If she cannot be part of the official tour, for legal reasons or simply because the club leadership is against people using their equipment without being a paying member, she could probably come along as long as she takes care of transport and equipment. In this case, it would be optimal if she could rent a kayak locally, instead of transporting one from Germany the way we do.

Searching on Google just delivers tons of hits for car renting, especially connected to kayak.com, but nothing which looked like a possibility to rent a kayak around that river. There was a rafting organiser, but it does not seem to have kayaks.

Does any of you know what is the closest/most convenient location for renting a kayak around the Allier river, especially the whitewater part? As we are driving from so far, it is OK if the place is not so close to the river itself, if it is not too far out of our way (roughly the Lyon direction).

Answer (score 3):

A quick search on Google yields [Canoe Val d'Allier](http://www.canoe-valdallier.com/tarifs-location.htm) as a valid rental company. The linked page shows the tariffs. For more results you want to [try googling `location kayak val d'Allier`](https://www.google.fr/search?ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=location+kayak+alliers&gfe_rd=cr&ei=55spVa7ZMrOx8wf7lYGIBg#q=location+kayak+allier) which is French for `kayak rental Allier valley`.